# Fill new column with value where column matches another column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a dataframe

```
name   | datetime | price
---------------------------
APL    |  10-1-12 | 1.92  
BBC    |  10-1-12 | 4.16
CPL    |  10-1-12 | 4.99
APL    |  10-2-12 | 2.05
BBC    |  10-2-12 | 5.16
CPL    |  10-2-12 | 3.99
```

I want to create a new column: APL_price, and anytime one of the other
names have a datetime that matches that of APL, I want it filled with the
APL price at that date like this:

```
name   | datetime | price | APL_price
-------------------------------------
APL    |  10-1-12 | 1.92  | 1.92 (or null is ok)
BBC    |  10-1-12 | 4.16  | 1.92
CPL    |  10-1-12 | 4.99  | 1.92
APL    |  10-2-12 | 2.05  | 2.05 (or null)
BBC    |  10-2-12 | 5.16  | 2.05
CPL    |  10-2-12 | 3.99  | 2.05
```

I was thinking about writing a helper function to iterate through everything
and find a datetime match, but not sure if theres a faster way.

Answer (score 0):

You can create `NaN`s for all values without values `APL` by [`Series.where`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.where.html) and then replace `NaN`s by forward filling by `ffill`:

```
df['APL_price'] = df['price'].where(df['name'] == 'APL').ffill()
```

Alternative solution with [`mask`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.mask.html) and inverted mask by `!=`:

```
df['APL_price'] = df['price'].mask(df['name'] != 'APL').ffill()
```

---

```
print (df)
  name  datetime  price  APL_price
0  APL     10112   1.92       1.92
1  BBC     10112   4.16       1.92
2  CPL     10112   4.99       1.92
3  APL     10212   2.05       2.05
4  BBC     10212   5.16       2.05
5  CPL     10212   3.99       2.05
```

Detail:

```
print (df['price'].where(df['name'] == 'APL'))
0    1.92
1     NaN
2     NaN
3    2.05
4     NaN
5     NaN
Name: price, dtype: float64
```

More general solution is similar in first step, but then use `groupby` by `datetime`s with `ffill` and `bfiil` for replace `NaN`s by both directions:

```
name = 'BBC'
df[name + '_price'] = df['price'].where(df['name'] == name)
df[name + '_price'] = (df.groupby('datetime')[name + '_price']
                         .apply(lambda x: x.ffill().bfill()))
print (df)
  name  datetime  price  BBC_price
0  APL     10112   1.92       4.16
1  BBC     10112   4.16       4.16
2  CPL     10112   4.99       4.16
3  APL     10212   2.05       5.16
4  BBC     10212   5.16       5.16
5  CPL     10212   3.99       5.16
```

Comment: Your output looks correct, but im a little curious how your code can distinguish between the different datetime rows.

Comment: Yes, I understand. I think it desired of data. If always first row is `APL` then it working nice. Or do you want more general solution, e.g. for `BBC` ?

Comment: Yes. The first row is not always APL..There is no set order. The only thing guaranteed is each row for APL has a unique datetime, and this datetime can always be matched to the other names and there respective datetime.

Comment: Thats actually too specific (Just changing one row) at a time: Just think if I have 100 different names, all of them need to be converted to the APL price when there dates in the row are the same as APL date.

Comment: Fills with NAN :(

Comment: OK, I think it is data problem. Are data confidental? If not, can you sent me your csv to my email in my profile?